# How to pass generic in an interface (nested generics)

Tags: c#, generics

I don't know whether I'm approaching this from the right angle or not, but either way I can't find syntax that works.

I want to pass 3 generic types to a method - from there I'll use reflection to create objects when I need them. However the object I'm passing is itself generic.

It sort of sounds like nested generics.

Let's say I create an interface:

```
    public interface IAgent<TRequest, TClient, TResponse>
    {
    }
```

I have a class like this that implements IAgent:

```
public class MyClass : IAgent<?>
```

Then I want to call a method something like this:

```
public method MyMethod<T>(T obj) where T : IAgent<?>
{
    // do somethings here
}
```

UPDATE

Here's what I currently do at class level.

```
public sealed class T3Agent
    : AppAgent<T3RequestAdapter, T3WebClient, T3ResponseAdapter>
{
}

public abstract class AppAgent<TRequest, TClient, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IAgentRequestAdapter
    where TClient : CustomWebClient
    where TResponse : IAgentResponseAdapter
{
    public AppResponse Submit(IAppForm appForm, ServiceLog log)
    {
    }
}

public sealed class AppManager
{
    public AppResponse Submit()
    {
        var t3 = new T3Agent();
        var t3Result = t3.Submit(Form, Log);

        return t3Result;
    }
}
```

In the final method, I instantiate a new class (T3Agent), but this is tightly coupled to T3. I want to be able to instantiate AppAgent once and pass the required generic types through the method rather than the class, so that I can reuse the class.

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you expect the `?` to do here... please give us more context.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I've added some further info under 'update' - this may be a little clearer

Comment: So what would your `Submit` method do? It could well be that you want a non-generic interface as well as a generic one...

Comment: No, the parent class of submit currently accepts generic types but this means a new class for every submission - I'm trying to do things - 1) create the class once (passing some non changing params in the c'tor), then submitting a number of times using the method, and 2) Making submission easy - instead of submit<t1request, t1client, t1response>() - I'll like to simply do it like this submit(t1agent), which contains the the generic classes.

Comment: But how is the submit method meant to get the request/response etc? It's still really not clear to me what you're trying to achieve... particularly as you haven't shown any methods in your interface, or what would call them...

Comment: Jon, sorry, i'm finding it difficult to describe this one accruately. I currently have a class/method that I use to do this. It works but I want to move the dependency for the generics from the class to the method. I've added a further update above, showing what I currently do - this may help to understand the situarion better.

Comment: I'm not seeing any updates more recent than 16 hours ago, which still doesn't show any implementation of `Submit` - without knowing how you're trying to *use* the argument and type arguments, it's hard to know what you really need. I can understand it being tricky to explain though.

Comment: Sorry Jon, you were too quick - please take another look.

Comment: Will do when I get a chance. It's probably worth making the update *before* you comment saying "I've added a further update" though :)

Comment: @JonSkeet - hey Jon, you forgotten about me?

Comment: Yes, I had - that's what happens when attention is drawn at the wrong time. Unfortunately, we *still* don't know anything about what the members of your interface are, or what your `Submit` method in `AppAgent` does - how it uses the type arguments, for a start. So it's still very unclear - I could potentially give you a solution which meets the needs I might *imagine* you have - but doesn't actually meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 options:

1. if you have to work with generic class T from Agent<T> you have to know the type anyway so you have to put it in your generic declaration (see TypeNeeded() method below)
2. If it is not necessary, then split up the interface in a not generic and in a generic interface and then let IAgent<T> extend IAgent (IAgent<T>: IAgent). Now you can create a method without to know the type for IAgent<T> (see method DoSomething())

   ```
   public interface IAgent
   {
       void Action( );
       int Calculate( );
   }

   public interface IAgent< T > : IAgent
   {
     void Set( T value );
   }

   public class MyClass
   {
       public void DoSomething< T >( T agent ) where T : IAgent
       {
           //...
       }

       public void TypeNeeded< T, V >( T agent ) where T : IAgent<V>
       {   
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the types for your generic interface yet, your class or method needs to be generic, too:

```
public class MyClass<TRequest, TClient, TResponse> : IAgent<TRequest, TClient, TResponse>
{
}
```

Or for the method:

```
public void MyMethod<T, TRequest, TClient, TResponse>(T obj) where T : IAgent<TRequest, TClient, TResponse>
{
    // do somethings here
}
```

Comment: Hi, not quite there - I've added an update that might make things a little clearer.